How to properly use AWS EC2 CodeDeploy from S3 bucket
I am currently trying to deploy a python script that will run every 3 days-1 week on AWS CodeDeploy. I have tried using GitHub, but got stuck when I got to the AppSpec file. I decided to switch over to using an S3 bucket. Can anyone help me understand if I can just upload my python code and commit it to deploy it? Or do I still need to use a form of the AppSpec file?
I have already tried creating an AppSpec file and looking through the tutorials/setup documents, but nothing seems to be very helpful. I have set up my instance, deployment groups, application, pipeline, roles, and policies correctly, and my deployments run, but they fail presumably due to the lack of an AppSpec file when I tried running things from my GitHub repo. I am hoping to use an S3 bucket to run my code directly, but I am not 100% sure on the setup and the process I need to take.

why you need code deploy if you run it 3 times a week ? is this a batch workload?

Yes, it's a batch workload. I am getting data from a site that changes information every so often, and it's much better for me to deploy the code on AWS than for me to manually run it locally 3 times a week.

The simplest way is to use AWS Batch to run it but you need to build a container image, push it in ECR and set the image in job definition
